# TableSorter jQuery plugin sort for Golf Scores

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I read the documentation on writing a custom parser for the tablesorter.  But I can't figure how how to make it work correctly for golf scores.

I would like scores sorted like so:
-11
-10
-9
-8
-7
-1
E
1
2
9
10
11

And I just can't get it to work like that.  Does anyone know how to make it soft correctly from negative 2 digits to 1 digits to the letter E instead of 0, and the to positive one digits and then positive 2 digits?

I tried this with no success:

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'golfscores', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.toLowerCase().replace(/E/,0); 
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 



$(document).ready(function() {
// call the tablesorter plugin
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
    headers: {0:{sorter:false},1:{sorter:'golfscores'}},
    widgets: ['zebra']
});
```

If it helps, the markup for the rows inside the table is like this:

```
<tr>
              <td align="center">
              <select name="ddl_slots_11052" class="ddl_slots" id="ddl_slots_11052">
                  <option value="">-</option>

                    <option value="1"  selected="selected">1</option>

                    <option value="2" >2</option>

                    <option value="3" >3</option>

                    <option value="4" >4</option>

                    <option value="5" >5</option>

                    <option value="6" >6</option>

                    <option value="7" >7</option>

                    <option value="8" >8</option>

                </select></td>



             <td align="center"> 
                    <strong>-3</strong>
                    </td>
              <td align="left">Larry</td>
              <td align="left">Larry</td>
              <td align="left">Mize</td>

              <td align="center">
                                    F
              </td>
              <td align="center">-3</td>
              </tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="score_11052" value="-3" />

            <tr>
              <td align="center">
              <select name="ddl_slots_10981" class="ddl_slots" id="ddl_slots_10981">
                  <option value="">-</option>

                    <option value="1" >1</option>

                    <option value="2"  selected="selected">2</option>

                    <option value="3" >3</option>

                    <option value="4" >4</option>

                    <option value="5" >5</option>

                    <option value="6" >6</option>

                    <option value="7" >7</option>

                    <option value="8" >8</option>

                </select></td>



             <td align="center"> 
                    <strong>2</strong>
                  </td>
              <td align="left">Jerry</td>
              <td align="left">Jerry</td>
              <td align="left">Pate</td>

              <td align="center">
                                    F
              </td>
              <td align="center">2</td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: You just need a custom sort function that will convert "E" to 0, then sort Asc. Don't forget to convert your strings to integers. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried this with no success:

Comment: Well, what did you try? why didn't it work? we're not going to build it from scratch for you.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't let me paste the code into the comment, I put it into the original question above

Comment: What exactly is the result? does it sort at all, just incorrectly? or does it not sort, does it throw an error, etc

Comment: Without the custom parser it sorts like this for some reason:
http://images.pgalinks.com/scoring/sortIssue.gif
If I try to add the custom parser, the sort on that column doesn't work at all, but there is no error.

Comment: Your parser works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fv7Vk/ I wonder if it has anything to do with the `<strong></strong>` you are using.

Comment: Ah, you're right! this did the trick
 return $(s).text().replace(/E/,0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be returning a number instead of the text, try changing the format function to this:

```
format: function(s) { 
    // Any letters will return as zero
    return parseFloat(s) || 0; 
},
```